# Greasemonkey/ Tampermonkey @match for a page with parameters

Tags: javascript, regex, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

I'm working on a script that must be executed in a certain page, depending on the parameters it has. The URL is like this:

```txt
http://example.com/page.php?key1=value1&key2=value2&...
```

And I need to match it when `page.php` has the `key1=value1` among its parameters.

Now I'm using

```txt
@match http://example.com/page.php?key1=value1&*
```

But it doesn't match if `page.php` has no other parameters. It also won't match if `key1` is not the first parameter either.

Is there any way to match a page according to a parameter?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

[`@match` only works on the protocol/scheme, host, and pathname of a URL.](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/match_patterns/)

To trigger off the query parameters, you can either use `@include` or use `@match` and also test the URL yourself.
Note that the `@match` approach performs faster.

With `@include`, you can use a regex syntax. See, also [Include and exclude rules](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Include_and_exclude_rules).

In this case, use **either:**

```
...
// @include  /^https?://example\.com/page\.php*key1=value1*/
// ==/UserScript==
```

**Or:**

```
...
// @match *://example.com/page.php*
// ==/UserScript==

if (/\bkey1=value1\b/.test (location.search) ) {
    // DO YOUR STUFF HERE.
}
```

Comment: This worked, except for a couple things. I used the `@match` example because `@include` didn't work (I will keep on trying, though).

Also, I had to do this match to make it work: `@match http://example.com/page.php*`

Comment: In latest version, `@match` does match the entire URI including query string. For example, `@match https://www.example.com` will not match `https://www.example.com?foo=bar`.

Comment: Multiple match statements in my TamperMonkey script may work for the first site listed, but not the others.  I went to using `include` with a regex, making sure not to forget the delimiters, and it seems I cannot use my custom usual delimiters instead.

Comment: The second example (using `@match`) worked for me! Just appending the `*` to the URL path works if it is placed before any query strings.

Comment: **Example** match any Google subdomain on http&https ... `@include      /^https?\:\/\/.*.google\..*\/.*$/` – Might help other dudes getting mad in trying to make it work like I did (also, don't forget to check "✅Enabled").

Comment: @Kamafeather, the `s?` is a good update; thanks.  The `\/`s are superfluous.  Which enabled check did you mean?

Comment: @BrockAdams I mean the first menu item when clicking on the Chrome extension icon; the first issue I had was that I needed to *enable* the global scripts execution from there; just a hint that might help some . About the slashes, yes, I thought so, but often I put them anyway to spare me eventual headaches (regex are quite sensitive to [my] mistakes, so I write them defensively )

Answer (score 9):

According to the documentation for `@match`, it doesn't appear that query string parameters are something the Greasemonkey engine will match on:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html

Comment: I believe the URL for this is now https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/match_patterns/