# Regex in @match not working

Tags: regex, userscripts, tampermonkey

I'm trying to insert a userscript into only the profile pages on instagram:

```
https://instagram.com/android
https://instagram.com/apple/
```

This is the match line:

```
// @match    /^https:\/\/www\.instagram\.com\/.*\//
```

But this isn't working at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try just `@match https://www.instagram.com/*`? I'm not too familiar with greasemonkey, as I use tampermonkey myself.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20462544/greasemonkey-tampermonkey-match-for-a-page-with-parameters It seems that `@include` supports proper regex, while `@match` doesn't.

Comment: @Davіd Actually I use Tampermonkey too. Dunno how I put the greasemonkey tag. Have removed it and added tampermonkey.

Comment: Regex only works in `@include` AFAIK.