# How to @match a URL hash in a userscript?

Tags: url, match, greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

I have a lot open tabs of a website - and I want to limit it to only one URL.

The problem is that the URL has `#` in it and I can't seem to @match it.

The  URL looks like: `https://xxx.xxxxxx.xxx/#/xxxxxx`

I tried:

```
// @match https://xxx.xxxxxx.xxx/#/xxxxxx - doesnt work

// @match https://xxx.xxxxxx.xxx/* - works - but works on all tabs

// @match https://xxx.xxxxxx.xxx/*/xxxxxx -doesnt work;/

// @match https://xxx.xxxxxx.xxx/\#/xxxxxx -doesnt work;/
```

Any combination of * and anything after it doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This question is closely related to: [Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey @match for a page with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20462544/greasemonkey-tampermonkey-match-for-a-page-with-parameters).

`@match` [only works on the protocol/scheme, host, and pathname of a URL.](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html)

To trigger off the hash value (officially [called the "fragment"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Generic_syntax)), you can either <del>use `@include`</del><sup>note-1</sup> or use `@match` and also test the URL yourself.

So use code like:

```
...
// @match    *://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/
// ==/UserScript==

if ( ! /#unicorn.*/.test(location.hash) )  return;

// REST OF YOUR CODE HERE.
```

For this example, that code:

- Runs : `https://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/#unicorn`
- Runs : `https://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/#unicorn-mode`, etc.
- Ignores: `https://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/#unicom`
- Ignores: `https://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/?foo=bar#unicorn` (Add `*` at end of `@match` if desired.)

IMPORTANT:  This is **for initial page loads only.** The `hash` can change after a page loads, and that's more complicated to deal with and not specified in this question.
So, for that kind of scenario, open a new question and refer to this one.

---

Notes:

1. Unfortunately, Tampermonkey has yet to implement `@include` the way Greasemonkey did, so the fragment/hash is ignored even in `@include` and [seems likely to remain that way for the near future](https://github.com/Tampermonkey/tampermonkey/issues/584#issuecomment-413627102).

Comment: thank you, that doesn't fully solve my problem, but i guess from your post - it is not possible right now.
Two notes regarding this workaround:
1) it will add to "active scripts count" +1 on everypage - despite them not using this particular script
2) it should be if ( ! /#\/unicorn.*/.test(location.hash) )  return; for my case :)
Thank you very much again:)

Comment: @Krzysztof, You're welcome.  Alas, the script count thing is not solvable until Tampermonkey's developer addresses it.  The `@include` method would solve that if it worked, and it might on Violentmonkey (haven't checked yet).

Comment: @Krzysztof, if this doesn't fully solve your problem, open a new question with the additional issues.  Include an [mcve] and/or a link to the target page(s).